# Java Illegal Exscape character in Icon path

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have a desktop application in swing using the netbeans IDE
 I want to change the default title image 
 I used the ImageIcon object and the `imageobject.getImage();`

below are the code snippets

```
IconImage img = new ImageIcon("\GNSSRegistry\src\my\gnssregsitry\NSSIcon\logobig.jpg");
```

then I set the following code in the jframe,s icon property window provided by the netbeans IDE

```
jframe.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

but netbeans complains that there is an illegal escape character in the image path provided 
 I am confuse I hope I am not getting the path setting wrong.

please help

Comment: looks like when I use the double slash and provide the full path name the frame is able to load the icon. But i want to be able to provide the icon path name relative to a folder in the project rather then the full path name referencing the hard disk root name eg. C:\\ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

backslashes `\` are used as escape characters you need to escape them inside strings so, your string should look like `"\\GNSSRegistry\\src\\my\\gnssregsitry\\NSSIcon\\logobig.jpg"`

Comment: or just use forward slashes, Windows doesn't care and it will work on any platform (OS X, Linux).

Comment: looks like when I use the double slash and provide the full path name the frame is able to load the icon. But i want to be able to provide the icon path name relative to a folder in the project rather then the full path name referencing the hard disk root name eg. C:\\

Comment: Then just give it the relative path from your java file